# В какой области данных хранятся члены класса?

Tags: c++, стек

Начал изучать ООП и появилось несколько вопросов.

1.Где хранятся переменные, которые являются полями-членами класса? То есть в какой области данных она будет хранится после создания объекта класса Alpha в функции main.
В куче или на стеке?

```
#include <iostream>

class Alpha{
public:
  int A;
};

int main(){
  Alpha object;
}
```

2.Где будет хранится в данном случае поле-член класса - int A? На стеке или в куче?

```
#include <iostream>

class Alpha{
public:
  int A;
};

int main(){
  Alpha* object = new Alpha;
}
```

Comment: 1/ В вашем коде - на стеке. 2. В "куче".

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, это как это: сам инстанс в куче, а поле в стеке? Ты точно вопрос не перепутал?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не понял, где я перепутал? Где я такое написал?

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, тьфу. Это я невнимательный. Я почему-то думал, что часть 1 спрашивает, где лежит `object->A`, а вторая - где лежит сам `*object`. А оказывается, в вопросе для этих случаев код разный.

Answer (score 2):

Инстанс класса - это непрерывный кусок памяти некоторого размера. Какого именно, можно узнать через `sizeof`. А значит поля класса хранятся там же, где и сам инстанс.

При этом, если полем является указатель, то говоря о нахождении в самом инстансе я имею в виду непосредственно указатель, а не то, на что он указывает.

Если полем является массив фиксированного размера (с динамическим можно что-то нахимичить, но вроде это не особо используется), то сами элементы массива хранятся внутри инстанса.

---

Память, выделенная через new и malloc выделяется в куче.

В стеке лежат только объекты, лежащие в переменных соответствующего типа.

PS: Ты `delete` забыл.

Answer (score 0):

Нестатические поля класса хранятся там же, где и объект класса, которому они принадлежат.

Способ создания объекта не является определяющим для размещения создаваемого объекта в том или ином месте. В общем случае для двух примеров в вопросе нет никакого способа определить, где будут реально созданы эти объекты. Единственное, что тут можно сказать, это то, что у первого объекта будет *automatic storage duration*, а у второго - *dynamic storage duration*.

Comment: Собственно предполагаемого четкого разделения на стек и кучу тоже нет, С++ - это не C#.

Comment: А существуют ли реальные реализации без разделения на стек и кучу?

Comment: Кроме стека и кучи еще есть регистры и буферы для объектов c thread_local и со статическим временем хранения. С другой стороны, куча может вообще не использоваться ни в каком виде, как например любят делать всякие утилиты для верификации, напрямую задействующие постраничное выделение памяти. Далее, объекты с automatic storage duration могут запросто размещаться на куче, или что там ее заменяет.

Comment: *"объекты с automatic storage duration могут запросто размещаться на куче"* В теории может и могут, но на практике - не верю.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Как я понял, попавшие в стандарт корутины так их и размещают, храня всякие локальные переменные в блоке корутины, который выделяется с использованием operator new.

Comment: Точно. Засчитано. :)